# Overriding class operator new and delete without changing the class

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to overriding `operator new` and `delete` for some class, but I don't want to modify the class itself.  Is there a way to achieve this?

Basically, I can't modify the class declaration, so the following approach won't work:

```
struct C {
  operator new (size_t) { ... }
};
```

And I don't want to modify the global one because the global `operator new` doesn't have the type information.

Is there a way to solve my problem?

EDIT: KerrekSB made a valid point here.  I'll reconsider my requirement.

Comment: Are you sure this is the right approach? Custom allocators might be a better solution to your problem.

Comment: I don't understand.  The class C is not necessarily an STL container.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? The class's `operator new` isn't going to be used in modern style C++ anyway, where you'd typically have a container with an allocator that used global-`::new` for construction, and you wouldn't really spell out an actual `new` in your own code.

Comment: Also note that type information is not *that* relevant in `operator new`, as it should only allocate memory (not initialize, not process)

Comment: Can you template the global new operator? And then specialize it for your class? 

I've never done it before, so I don't know if new has any restrictions against that.

Comment: Kerrek and David's comments are very pertinent here -- at what point would you ever do `new C` in your code? (Hint: _you probably don't need to_.)

Answer (score 0):

Best approximation I can think of is have a class that inherits from the one you don't want to modify, and override new and delete in the child.  Not clear that solves your problem, though.

Comment: if I have `struct D : C { operator new (size_t) {...} };`, 
does it mean `new C` will call this?  There are too many call sites so I can't modify them all.

Comment: No, it won't.  I was afraid this might be your problem.

Comment: If the existing class destructor is not virtual you might run into undefined behavior (if you do not delete through a pointer to the new derived type)